# Rest service that accepts a URL as a parameter

Tags: rest, url

I'm trying to pass a complete URL as a parameter to a java-based REST service (GET), but I'm not sure how to format it in order to avoid a "HTTP 400 Bad Request".  I've tried Base64 encoding, but still get the 400 error.  I *think* part of the problem is that the url contains a question mark, "?", since it seems to be fine if I remove that and pass the url as-is.  I'm not sure what is the problem when its encoded.

example url - http://my.site.com/testing-service?some+parms

method annotations:

```
@GET
@Path("/{fullurl}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response findByUrl(@PathParam("fullurl") String fullurl)
...
```

Comment: Getting a 400 error from the server usually means that the request is malformed or has parameters or its values missing or present that should not be. In most APIs, query parameters expect a non-null value separated by the equal sign from the parameter key. So http://my.site.com/testing-service?url=base64encodedurl

Comment: in which language are you implementing the rest service?
I tried a quick test with .net handler and it gets entire url without problem.

Can you post your code please? This will help us tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

(I've updated the description with a little more detail per the first couple of comments)

Apparently the encoding approach was close, but Base64 (java or commons-code) didn't work for whatever reason (length perhaps?).  I found switching to Base32 (commons-code) works for my situation.